# Octobercms export with dynamic fileName

Tags: octobercms

I've been using Octobercms for a while and have read [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/import-export) about exporting data as csv.  However nothing is mentioned a single thing about exporting file with a dynamic name because I needed to append text or set a filename with a date.
Is this a sort of limitation with Octobercms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to override the default behavior.

> In your controller where you added `Backend.Behaviors.ImportExportController` `ImportExport Behavior`, you can add the `download` method, and there you can change the name of downloading the CSV file.

```php
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public $implement = [
        'Backend.Behaviors.FormController',
        'Backend.Behaviors.ListController',
        'Backend.Behaviors.ImportExportController' // HERE
    ];

    public function download($name, $outputName = null) // <-- THIS method
    {
        $this->pageTitle = $this->pageTitle
            ?: Lang::get($this->asExtension('ImportExportController')
                     ->getConfig('export[title]', 'Export records'));

        // $newOutputName = 'my_new_name.csv'; // <-- HERE you can update name of CSV file
        $outputName = explode('.', $outputName)[0];
        $outputName = $outputName . '-' . date('d-m-Y') . '.csv';
        $newOutputName = $outputName;
        return $this->asExtension('ImportExportController')
                     ->exportGetModel()->download($name, $newOutputName);
    }

    //     ... other code

}
```

to append date to existing name

```php
// $outputName its coming from the config
$outputName = explode('.', $outputName)[0];
$outputName = $outputName . '-' . date('d-m-Y') . '.csv';
$newOutputName = $outputName;
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Would like to clarify, I shouldn't touch the $name variable right? since that is the file name I only have to manipulate the second parameter is that right?

Comment: I just have one problem the name `config_import_export.yaml: fileName: products.csv gets overwritten. I dont want the name of my products get overwritten and the fileType

I wanted it to look like "products 05-21-1995.csv" or something like that

Comment: updated code please check, it should help :), just make format as you like